# How to prove equality from equality of Some

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I want to prove equality of two nat numbers in Coq:

```
a, b : nat
Heq : Some a = Some b
============================
a = b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an equality such as this, usually, the quickest way to go is by using the `inversion` tactic which will more or less exploit injectivity of constructors.

```
Lemma foo :
  forall (a b : nat),
    Some a = Some b ->
    a = b.
Proof.
  intros a b e. inversion e. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

---

The case of `Some` however is special enough that you might want to write it differently (especially if you ant to be able to read the proof that's generated).
You can write some *get* function for `option` using a default value:

```
Definition get_opt_default {A : Type} (x : A) (o : option A) :=
  match o with
  | Some a => a
  | None => x
  end.
```

So that `get_opt_default x (Some a) = a`.
Now using `f_equal (get_opt_default a)` on equality `Some a = Some b`
you get

```
get_opt_default a (Some a) = get_opt_default a (Some b)
```

which simplifies to

```
a = b
```

```
Lemma Some_inj :
  forall A (a b : A),
    Some a = Some b ->
    a = b.
Proof.
  intros a b e.
  apply (f_equal (get_opt_default a)) in e.
  cbn in e.
  exact e.
Qed.
```

This is something that can be done in general. Basically you write an extractor for your value as a function and you apply it to both sides of the equality.
By computation it will yield the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

The `congruence` tactic is powerful enough to solve this goal by itself.  More generally, there are situations where you would like to derive `a = b` as an additional hypothesis starting from an equality `H : x = y` of terms that begin with the same constructor.  In this case, you can call

```
injection H.
```

to extract the equalities implied by this hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is instructive to write the basic lemma down:

```
Definition some_inj A (x y : A) (h_eq : Some x = Some y) : x = y :=
  match h_eq with
  | eq_refl _ => eq_refl
  end.
```

Actually, that seems surprising; indeed Coq is elaborating the match to help the user, and the reality is a bit more ugly, as witnessed by the term:

```
Print some_inj.

Definition some_inj A (x y : A) (h_eq : Some x = Some y) : x = y :=
  match h_eq in (_ = option_y)
        return match option_y with
               | Some y => x = y
               | None => IDProp
               end
  with
  | eq_refl => eq_refl
  end.
```

So indeed the return type of the match is doing quite a bit of work to tell Coq that the constructor is injective.